# Let X be a measurable set with $ \mu (X) < \infty $ and $ 1 \leq p < \infty $... ($L^p$ spaces

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces

Let X be a measurable set with $ \mu (X) < \infty $ and $ 1 \leq p < \infty $

Let $ (f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset X $ and $f \in L^{p}(X)$ with $\lim_{n \to \infty}||f_n - f|| = 0 $

Show that $ \forall$   $\epsilon >0  \ \exists \ \delta >0 $ such that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} $

$\int_{E}|f_n| \leq \epsilon \ \forall \ E \subset X$  with $\mu(E)<\delta$

Since $ | f_n |^p $ is integrable and positive, we can find $ \delta $ that for every set $ E \subset X $ with $ \mu(E) < \delta $ that $ \int_{E}|f_n |^p <\epsilon $

The problem is that this goes for $ f_n $ specifically for the $ n $ chosen, how can I use the limit of $ ||f_n -f || $ to generalize for all $ n$?

Comment: Hint: sequence converges in $L^1(\mu)$ iff the sequence convergences in measure and the sequence is uniform integrable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the measure space is finite convergence in $L^p$ implies convergence in $L^1$. So for a given $\epsilon$ choose $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $||f_n-f||_1<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ for all $n>n_0$. Now, since $f\in L^1$ we know that there is $0<\delta$ such that for all $E\subseteq X$ with $\mu(E)<\delta$ we have $\int_E |f|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Alright, so for all $n>n_0$ and each such set $E$:

$\int_E |f_n|=\int_E |f_n-f+f|\leq\int_E |f_n-f|+\int_E |f|\leq\int_X |f_n-f|+\int_E |f|\leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon$

So this $\delta$ works for all $n>n_0$. Now, before $n_0$ there are only finitely many functions in the sequence. So for each $n\leq n_0$ choose $\delta_n$ which works for $f_n$ and then take $\min\{\delta_1,...,\delta_{n_0},\delta\}$.

Comment: I understood, my friend, just a little doubt.
That limit of $ || f_n - f ||$ which is to say that $f_n$ converge to $f $ in $ L ^ p $?

Comment: Well, I assumed that it is the norm of $L^p$. What is written in your exercise?

Comment: My comment is wrong, you missed the $ p $ on $ || f_n - f || p $

Comment: My only question was.
The $ \lim_ {n \to \infty} || f_n -f ||_p = 0 $ implies that $f_n$ converges to $f $in $ L ^ p $ ?? I get confused by the norm

Comment: $\lim_{n\to\infty} ||f_n-f||_p=0$ is exactly the definition of convergence in $L^p$.

Comment: The fact that $ f_n \to f $ in $ L^p $ implies that $ f_n \to f $ in $L^1 $is only because $ L^p \subset L^1 $?

Comment: It follows from Holder's inequality: $\int_X |f_n-f|\leq (\int_X 1^q)^\frac{1}{q}(\int_X |f_n-f|^p)^\frac{1}{p}$ when $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$. Since the measure space is finite $(\int_X 1)^\frac{1}{q}$ is just a finite constant. So since we know that $(\int_X |f_n-f|^p)^\frac{1}{p}\to 0$ the result follows.

Comment: Now I went to reread the demonstration and realized that it was not proven what you asked for, you forgot the "p".
Why does $ \int_{E}f_{n} < \epsilon $ directly imply the result?

Comment: I just answered the question you asked. You asked "Show that $\forall\epsilon>0\exists\delta>0$ such that $\forall n\in\mathbb{N} \int_E |f_n|\leq\epsilon\forall E\subset X$ with $\mu(E)<\delta$".